# Apache crashes every other time PHP script is ran...Windows

Tags: php, .net, windows, com

XAMPP installation (Apache, MySQL, PHP, Perl) is crashing every other time I call a DOTNET object through PHP. For instance the sample code on php.net

```
<?php
  $stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");
  $stack->Push(".Net");
  $stack->Push("Hello ");
  echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();
  //$stack = NULL; tried this, with no luck
?>
```

This will display `Hello .Net` the first time, but if I refresh the page Apache crashes and immediately restarts. If I refresh again, I see `Hello .Net`. If I refresh again, you guessed it; Apache crashes....any ideas? Maybe I should be releasing the object somehow?

Thanks

Apache Log:

```
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:44 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) SVN/1.6.6 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:44 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:44 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5156
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:45 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:45 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:46 2012] [notice] Child 5156: Child process is running
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:46 2012] [notice] Child 5156: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:46 2012] [notice] Child 5156: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:46 2012] [notice] Child 5156: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:46 2012] [notice] Child 5156: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:46 2012] [notice] Child 5156: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:46 2012] [notice] Child 5156: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:49 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:50 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:50 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:51 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) SVN/1.6.6 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:51 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:51 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5948
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:51 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:51 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:52 2012] [notice] Child 5948: Child process is running
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:52 2012] [notice] Child 5948: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:52 2012] [notice] Child 5948: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:52 2012] [notice] Child 5948: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:52 2012] [notice] Child 5948: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:52 2012] [notice] Child 5948: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:52 2012] [notice] Child 5948: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:55 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:55 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:55 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:57 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) SVN/1.6.6 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:57 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:57 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4596
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:58 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:58 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:59 2012] [notice] Child 4596: Child process is running
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:59 2012] [notice] Child 4596: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:59 2012] [notice] Child 4596: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:59 2012] [notice] Child 4596: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:59 2012] [notice] Child 4596: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:59 2012] [notice] Child 4596: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Wed Feb 29 00:59:59 2012] [notice] Child 4596: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

This shows a few reboots.

Comment: Are you using [PHP as CGI by chance?](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53140)

Comment: What is the php version?

Comment: I can't replicate the crash though i'm not using XAMPP. Is your apache log saying anything?

Comment: I'm running PHP 5.3.8, Apache 2.2.21

Comment: Does executing it directly through php return the same issue? i.e. Command prompt: `php.exe /path/to/file.php`

Comment: @BradChristie actually, every time through the command prompt it works. I tried about 40 times in 30 seconds with no errors.

Comment: @Mike: oddly enough it's following suit with everything mentioned in that previous bug article I mentioned. Unfortunately there's no solution. I would venture to say report it as a bug with your environment and reference the IIS/FastCGI bug with your report.

Comment: Could I get around this by running php with `shell_exec` from within the script?

Comment: 3221225477 = 0xC0000005 = Access violation.

Answer (score 1):

file could be

```
$stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");
$stack->Push(".Net");
```

create a file with your commands, instead of calling directly use below call

```
$output = exec("php dotnet.php"); 

echo $output;
```